# Using Spring Security to get Custom Attributes in Cognito

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I´m trying to get my custom attributes from amazon cognito inside a spring security app, and i´m struggling with that

The app already does authentication via Jwt but i didn´t manage to get more info from the logged user...

There is some known way to get my cognito custom user attributes from my JWT or something like that?

my configuration class looks like that :

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
            .authorizeRequests(expressionInterceptUrlRegistry -> expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
}
```

and i´m trying to get some user information in my OncePerRequest filter, here :

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    var principal = (JwtAuthenticationToken)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String clientId = null;
    String userId = null;
    if (principal != null) {
        [ADD SOME CODE TO GET COGNITO CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE]
        clientId = ((Jwt) principal.getPrincipal()).getClaim("client_id").toString();
        userId = principal.getName();
    }
```

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom attributes comes with "custom:" prefix. So you can use the same above code,

```
clientId = ((Jwt) principal.getPrincipal()).getClaim("custom:xxx").toString();
```